# ellipses(not)However, don't spend too long in the sun- 15 minutes a day without a sunscreen is a healthy amount, and not at midday

Tags: modal-verbs

Could you please help me to complete the second part of the ellipses sentences?

> **First sentence**: However, don't spend too long in the sun- 15 minutes a day without a sunscreen is a healthy amount, and not at
>   midday.

***Here , "not" represents as:***

**My analysis**: However, don't spend too long in the sun- 15 minutes a day without a sunscreen is a healthy amount, and don't spend too long in the sun at midday.

> I am not sure here 'not' represents the verb 'spend' or the verb 'is'
>   (for example, 15 minutes at midday without a sunscreen is not a
>   healthy amount).

Comment: This is stating that 15 minutes a day is healthy - but not 15 minutes at midday, when the sun is strongest.

Comment: I think Davo's interpretation is correct, but the sentence is not very clear - it would be much clearer if it said **but** not at midday.

Answer (score 1):

In spoken English it would go like this:

> However, don't spend too long in the sun—15 minutes a day without a
>   sunscreen is a healthy amount—and not at midday.

The time-of-day stricture "and not at midday" parallels "don't spend *too long*".

The independent clause in the middle of the sentence is a parenthetic.

I would paraphrase:

Don't spend too long in the sun and don't (spend time in the sun) at midday. No more than fifteen minutes a day without sunscreen is healthy.

Comment: what you said is in contrast with what comments above. Which one is correct?

Comment: Since "and not at midday" could be tacked onto either clause, the one beginning "don't spend too long..." or the one beginning "15 minutes a day ...is", we must look to the clauses themselves to see which one of them is the better candidate. The **negative** "and not at midday" extends the restriction introduced in the "don't spend too long" clause, and for that reason the opening clause is the better candidate of the two.  If it were being tacked onto the "15 minutes is" clause, we'd expect "but", not "and".  That sentence is rather impromptu English and is not as clear as it could be.